I cant figure out Button switches Kotlin Jetpack Compose
I have 2 custom Image buttons in my UI (button 1 and button 2). When a the first button is  activated it switches to a different image. This part I figured out  using  the IconToggleButton. However, when the Second  button  is activated I want to first button to return to turn off and the  image to  switch back to its  original state and vise versa.  I accomplished already in XML but im struggling with this in Jetpack Compose.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            ButtonSwitchSweetVibrationsTheme {
                CompactView()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CompactView() {


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = Yellow)
    ) {

        val textPadding = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
        val textColor = Color.White

        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        ) {

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(0.dp, 15.dp, 0.dp, 75.dp)
                    .background(color = Red),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.sweetlogo),
                contentDescription = "border",
            )

            Row(

                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Green),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray),

                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {


                    Text(
                        text = "First Button", textPadding, textColor
                    )


                }

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.LightGray),
                    // .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {


                    Text(
                        text = "Second Button", textPadding, textColor
                    )


                }

            }

        }
    }


}


@Composable
fun ButtonEffect() {
    var copperBtn: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }


    IconToggleButton(
        modifier = Modifier

            .size(125.dp),


        checked = copperBtn,
        onCheckedChange = {
            copperBtn = !copperBtn
        }) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.copperbuttonclicked),
            contentDescription = "Classic Vibration",

            )


        if (copperBtn == false) {
            // Handling vibrations for devices below Android 10


            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.copperbutton),
                contentDescription = "Hump Vibration",

                )

        }


    }


}


What do you mean by activated button? Do you mean clicked button?

Yes, each button is a simple on / off switch. when a button is clicked it's image changesb(on). When it's clicked again it returns to its original state(off). This is already achieved. The problem o have is when the first button is clicked (on) and the other ibutton s then clicked on I want the first button to turn off and return to its original image/ off

Where is the ButtonEffect Composable called? Right now, it is just a dangling Composable.

You need to have two state for each button and manipulate them however you want in onCheckedChange callbacks.

A short sample code is shown below.
@Composable
fun ButtonTest() {
    Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {

        var firstButtonChecked by remember {
            mutableStateOf(true)
        }
        var secondButtonChecked by remember {
            mutableStateOf(!firstButtonChecked)
        }
        IconToggleButton(
                checked = firstButtonChecked,
                onCheckedChange = {
                    firstButtonChecked = it
                }
        ) {
            if (firstButtonChecked) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.CheckCircle, contentDescription = null)
            } else {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.CheckCircle, contentDescription = null)
            }
        }
        IconToggleButton(
                checked = secondButtonChecked,
                onCheckedChange = {
                    secondButtonChecked = it
                    if (firstButtonChecked){
                        firstButtonChecked = false
                    }
                }
        ) {
            if (secondButtonChecked) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ThumbUp, contentDescription = null)
            } else {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.ThumbUp, contentDescription = null)
            }
        }
    }
}

